# Serve Entire React CRA from AWS S3 bucket using Express

Tags: express, amazon-s3, reverse-proxy

I am basically trying to use express as a sort of reverse proxy. My end goal is to serve up different react CRA bundles to different users. Right now though I am just working on a Proof of Concept to see if it is even possible to do this.

TLDR Goal:

- use express to point to a specific CRA bundle stored in a s3 bucket and serve it

This is the code I am using in express:

```js
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  const bucketParams = {
    Bucket: 'some-dumb-bucket',
    Key: 'cra/index.html'
  };

  s3.getObject(bucketParams)
  .on('httpHeaders', function (statusCode, headers) {
    res.set('Content-Length', headers['content-length']);
    res.set('Content-Type', headers['content-type']);
    res.set('Last-Modified', headers['last-modified']);
    this.response.httpResponse.createUnbufferedStream()
      .pipe(res);
    })
    .send();
})
```

The problem I am encountering is that all of my content is coming back with wrong headers. When I go into s3 and view the metadata it has the right headers so why is it fetching all the headers as "text/html"?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong! It was looping through and grabbing the same index.html headers. Fix:

```js
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  const bucketParams = {
    Bucket: 'some-dumb-bucket',
    Key: 'auth/index.html'
  };

  if (req.url && req.url !== '/') {
    bucketParams.Key = `auth${req.url}`;
  } else
   bucketParams.Key = `auth/index.html`;

  // send the assets over from s3
  s3.getObject(bucketParams)
    .on('httpHeaders', function (statusCode, headers) {
      res.set('Content-Length', headers['content-length']);
      res.set('Content-Type', headers['content-type']);
      res.set('Last-Modified', headers['last-modified']);
      res.set('ETag', headers['etag']);
      this.response.httpResponse.createUnbufferedStream()
        .pipe(res);
    })
    .send();
});
```

Code could be a tiny bit cleaner but PoC working.